# how to release docker image better to cooperation with others which depends our image

Tags: docker, release

we are the base plugin, is currently providing the underlying docker environment. Every time the package is business from us take the docker mirror and then add it above. Now the dilemma is that our plug-in is not so perfect, there will always be a patch on the. Once the plugin needs to patch it must inform all businesses to follow the brush pack - the communication cost exponentially increased. Causing the relevant personnel to be exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your other parties are referencing your image in their own Docker environment.

One workaround would be for their own Dockerfile to start with:

```
FROM yourPLuginImage:latest
```

Then each morning, they can do a `docker pull` + `docker build`: if the plugin has not changed, nothing will happen.
That way, they don't have to wait for an official communication.